# datadog API python auth

Tags: python, datadog

Is there a basic example of how to authenticate to datadog using the python lib `datadog_api_client.v2`? I was looking at their documentation https://datadoghq.dev/datadog-api-client-python/v2/#apikeyauth and am not seeing any examples I was expecting something along the lines of:

```
import datadog_api_client.v2
import os
from datadog_api_client.v2 import list_tag_configurations

configuration = datadog_api_client.v2.Configuration(
    host = "https://api.datadoghq.com"
)

configuration.api_key['apiKeyAuth'] = os.getenv('123')

with datadog_api_client.v2.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = list_tag_configurations(api_client)
    print(api_instance)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://pypi.org/project/datadog-api-client/ ? The configuration section is probably what you are looking for.
```configuration = datadog_api_client.v1.Configuration(
    host = "https://api.datadoghq.com"
)

# Configure API key authorization: apiKeyAuth
configuration.api_key['apiKeyAuth'] = os.getenv('DD_CLIENT_API_KEY')
configuration.api_key['appKeyAuth'] = os.getenv('DD_CLIENT_APP_KEY')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only v2 authentication example I found on how to use `Configuration` in the github repo source code for [datadog_api_client / v2 / configuration.py starting on line 83](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-api-client-python/blob/f105f7acc451c10472a3a538846b92500344f587/src/datadog_api_client/v2/configuration.py#L96):

```
conf = datadog_api_client.v2.Configuration(
    api_key={'cookieAuth': 'abc123'}
    api_key_prefix={'cookieAuth': 'JSESSIONID'}
)
```

My guess is using the example for v1 for authentication but changing v1 to v2 would work.

This is the first part of their v1 example from their root github [readme.md](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-api-client-python/)

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dateutil_parser
import datadog_api_client.v1
from datadog_api_client.v1.api import aws_integration_api
from datadog_api_client.v1.models import *
from pprint import pprint

# Defining the host is optional and defaults to https://api.datadoghq.com
# See configuration.py for a list of all supported configuration parameters.
configuration = datadog_api_client.v1.Configuration(
    host = "https://api.datadoghq.com"
)

# The client must configure the authentication and authorization parameters
# in accordance with the API server security policy.
# Examples for each auth method are provided below, use the example that
# satisfies your auth use case.

# Configure API key authorization: apiKeyAuth
configuration.api_key['apiKeyAuth'] = os.getenv('DD_CLIENT_API_KEY')

# Configure API key authorization: appKeyAuth
configuration.api_key['appKeyAuth'] = os.getenv('DD_CLIENT_APP_KEY')
```

And here's an example from their documentation for v2 on `list_tag_configurations`: https://datadoghq.dev/datadog-api-client-python/v2/MetricsApi/#list_tag_configurations

Comment: this is correct but these API's do not work without an additional license https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/faq/metrics-without-limits/